# Can I get the size of virtual method table with g++

Tags: g++

I'm working on a program with a plugin system which works by the plugins deriving from an abstract class. The program is written in c++ and built with g++.

Obviously when new functions are added to the abstract class it will make the plugin interface incompatible with previous versions. I would like to automatically detect this and mark the plugins as incompatible.

To do this I would like to get the size of the virtual method table for the abstract class. Is there any way to do so for a program compiled with g++ (I know this will not be possible using only standard c++ features).

I would prefer a solution that works within the program, but a method that involves looking at the object files with external tools would also be acceptable.

Comment: the size is a low indicator, if a virtual method is removed and an other added the size will be the same but to recompile is needed at least to check the removed method is not used, the order can also change and to recompile is needed even the size did not change, and what about changes concerning the attributes etc also requiring to recompile ?

Comment: may be look at [How does the virtual inheritance table work in g++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9947805/how-does-the-virtual-inheritance-table-work-in-g), also [Print layout of C++ object with g++ compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979606/print-layout-of-c-object-with-g-compiler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing (guided somewhat by the comments). This goes a bit further than simply the size of the virtual method table.

First I used sed to replace "= 0" with "{}", the reason for doing this is that the dumped class hierarchy has more information for real methods than for pure virtual ones. Then I piped the output of that into g++ with the `-fdump-class-hierarchy` option.

```
sed 's/= 0/{}/' <my header> | g++ -c -fdump-class-hierarchy <search path arguments> -x c++ -o dummy.o -"
```

This created a file called "-.002t.class" (I understand the middle part varies with the g++ version) with details of all the VMTs and the size and alignment of the classes (but sadly not full details of their fields)

I then used python to pick out the sections for the class I was interested in, edit out the large hexadecimal numbers (I'm not sure of the meaning of said numbers but they do not appear to be related to the structure of the classes, i'm guessing they are addresses in the object file or something) and feed them (along with some other data) to a hash function to generate a "plugin compatibility ID".

Comment: I got the liberty to fix some typos, mainly to correct the g++ option

Comment: Note Since GCC version 8.0 `-fdump-class-hierarchy` is renamed `-fdump-lang-class` ( https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=89712 )